# Create per-user admin key in Simperium

Tags: http, simperium

The http API docs request that a special token be created for several operations (e.g. List Buckets, All Changes)

X-Simperium-Token — Authentication token must have been created using an API key that has admin privileges

How do I create this token?

I have tried a few things:

1. `curl -H 'X-Simperium-Token: {my admin key}' https://api.simperium.com/1/{app_name}/buckets`. 
   This results in the "meta" buckets `{"buckets": [{"name": "exception"}, {"name": "code"}, {"name": "message"}]}` which is kind of interesting.
2. `curl -H 'X-Simperium-API-Key: {my admin key}' -d '{"username":"{valid user}", "password":"{valid password}"}' https://auth.simperium.com/1/{app_name}/authorize/`.
   Result: invalid app credentials
3. Authorize with my normal key, which works fine and gives me an access token which I can use for the other (non-admin) operations.

My thinking is that I need to pass in my admin key into 'authorize' somehow and generate an auth token blessed with admin privileges for this user (to list all of his buckets, for example).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the admin key directly for the token anywhere that requires a token that was created with an API key with admin privileges. We're currently working on the UI to actually create these API keys with different options. In the meantime, you can either use the admin key from your dashboard directly, or contact us and we can create one for you.